# 'Box not found.' message

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am developing a Flutter app that uses Hive for local data storage. I have set up the necessary Hive initialisation and box opening in my 'main.dart' file, and the app starts without any errors. However, when I navigate to the 'NewsPage' section of the app, I encounter the following error: HiveError: Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?
I have double-checked and confirmed that the box is opened correctly in the main.dart file, and the box name is consistent throughout the app. The purpose of this box is to locally store information from online news articles.

In hive setup, I have registered the NewsArticle class with the appropriate adapter.

```
// hive_setup.dart file
Future<void> setupHive() async {
  final appDocumentDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDir.path);

  Hive.registerAdapter<NewsArticle>(NewsArticleAdapter());
}
```

In the boxes file, I have defined the boxNewsArticle variable and newsArticleBoxName.

```
// boxes.dart file
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'model/newsarticle_model.dart';

Box<NewsArticle>? boxNewsArticle;
String newsArticleBoxName = 'newsarticleBox';

Future<void> openBoxes([String? s]) async {
  boxNewsArticle = await Hive.openBox<NewsArticle>(newsArticleBoxName);

}
```

In the main file, I call the setupHive and openBoxes functions.

```
// main.dart file
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'boxes.dart';
import 'hive_setup.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // ... other code ...

  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await setupHive();
  await openBoxes();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Lastly in the news page file, I try to access the box using _readArticlesFromHive.

```
// news_page.dart file
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'boxes.dart';
import 'model/newsarticle_model.dart';

// ... other code ...

Future<void> _readArticlesFromHive() async {
    if (boxNewsArticle == null) {
      return;
    }
    final newsArticleBox = Hive.box<NewsArticle>(newsArticleBoxName); 
    final newsArticle = newsArticleBox.get('sampleKey');
    if (newsArticle != null) {
    }
  }
```

Even after all this, I still encounter the "HiveError: Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?" error when I navigate to the NewsPage section of the app.

Some changes I made that still yielded the same error message are here.

In the main file:

```
// main.dart file
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'boxes.dart';
import 'hive_setup.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // ... other code ...

  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await setupHive();
  await Hive.openBox<NewsArticle>('newsarticleBox');

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```